# i18n pluralize dont work correct on production unicorn and nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

When I run my app using default WEBrick server, and set locale  works perfectly.
However, when I use Nginx and Unicorn to run my app, i18n doesnt work like it does in WEBrick.

I have following method

```
t('law_articles.count', count: @law_articles.total_count)
```

**ru.yml**

```
law_articles:
    count:
      zero: 'text 1'
      one: 'text 2'
      few: 'text %{count} text3'
      many: 'text %{count} text3'
      other: 'text %{count} text4'
```

On localhost are working all correct. but on production, remote server nginx  + unicorn not correct. For example `@law_articles.total_count` return 43, but render on html every time **text 1**

Could anyone please teach me how to make i18n work?I'm stack all day....
Please excuse my poor English skill...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have page caching?

Comment: i cleaned with rake tmp:cache:clear
rake assets:clean, restart unicorn, same output: text1

Comment: How are you setting up `i18n ` to use ru? Are you changing the default to `ru`?

Comment: yes, sure. if no, than dont returned text1. maybe problem in setting cache with nginx?